# Selecting in a dictionary (tuple, value) n, n+1 records/observations from pandas dataframe based on 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe example and would like to select extract as dictionary the consecutive "id" grouped, will work as a dataframe or matrix too.

Edit of the dataframe so can clear the confusion

```
sales = [('name', ['C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA','C', 'N', 'CA','C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA', 'C', 'N', 'CA', 'C']),
     ('id', [5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 2, 18]),
     ('vect1', [210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 200, 200, 210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 45, 200, 210, 90]),
     ('vect2', [210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 200, 140, 215, 95, 340, 215, 95, 240, 215, 95, 65, 200, 210, 90]),
     ('vect3', [210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 200, 240, 115, 35, 340, 115, 35, 140, 115, 35, 35, 200, 210, 90]),
     ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)#len1919


selected = df['name'].groupby(df['id']) 
gr_data = df.groupby('name')
```

Dataframe is not limited to this observations and id (id can start at any number in the dataset but will extract only consecutive ones), what I try to get is ***n, n+1, n+2, n+3*** , this is for **id** column the consecutiveness but should follow strict order as is the name, tried to group but does't work the way I need ...

this is what i'm looking for as a consecutive order:

```
dC13 =[{...},
   {(C, 13): [200,  140,    240]},
   {(N, 14): [210,  215,    240]},
   {(CA, 14): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, 14): [200,  340,    340]},
   {(N, 15): [210,  215,    115]},
   {(CA, 15): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, 15): [200,  240,    140]},
   {(N, 16): [210,  215,    115]},
   {(CA, 16): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, 16): [45,   65, 35]},
   {...}]
```

So final result will be like following:

```
 dC_n =[{...},
   {(C, n): [200,   140,    240]},
   {(N, n+1): [210, 215,    240]},
   {(CA, n+1): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+1): [200, 340,    340]},
   {(N, n+2): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA, n+2): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+2): [200, 240,    140]},
   {(N, n+3): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA,n+3): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, n+3): [45,  65, 35]},
   {(N, n+4): [210, 215,    240]},
   {(CA, n+4): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+4): [200, 340,    340]},
   {(N, n+5): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA, n+5): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+5): [200, 240,    140]},
   {(N, n+6): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA,n+6): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, n+6): [45,  65, 35]},
   {(N, n+7): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA,n+7): [90,  95, 35]},
   {(C, n+7): [45,  65, 35]},
   {(N, n+8): [210, 215,    240]},
   {(CA, n+8): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+8): [200, 340,    340]},
   {(N, n+9): [210, 215,    115]},
   {(CA, n+9): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+9): [200, 240,    140]},
   {(N, n+10): [210,    215,    115]},
   {(CA,n+10): [90, 95, 35]},
   {(C, n+10): [45, 65, 35]},
   {...}]
```

#### vectors are just sample.

P.S: from comments adding details:

The key is the combination from name and id column, values is the vect1, vect2, vect3.

What I try to do is the output to be only as a consecutive id from having exactly forming this "pattern": **C_n', 'N_n+1', 'CA_n+1', 'C_n+1' , 'N_n+2', 'CA_n+2','C_n+2'**, followed by new sequence **C_n+2', 'N_n+3', 'CA_n+3', 'C_n+3' , 'N', 'CA','C'** where 'C_n'  is the . Example does show sample of how should look with consecutive, so in this case n=13, n+1=14 , n+2 = 15 etc than another pattern in the same dataset can start over n=18, n+1=19 (checking everything with id=19), n+2=20(checking everything with id=20) etc.

I create the tuple as a combination of 2 columns from above:

```
df['new_col'] = list(zip(df.name, df.id))
```

So in the dataset **C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA','C'** is not all time consecutive (C = 5, N= 13, CA= 13 will not be a pattern looking for because **id** is not consecutive ... ), I just look at consecutive ones and output them as a dictionary or will work as a dataframe/matrix too, multiple dictionaries composing from this patter with consecutive **id** : C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA','C'.

I listed as dictionary because ultimately i can convert dict to dataframe as:

```
df_readyC13 = pd.DataFrame(dC13)
df_readyC_n = pd.DataFrame(dC_n) #where C_n is the sstart of the new consecutive sequence C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA','C'
```

I'm thinking that for every disconnected pattern 'C', 'N', 'CA', 'C_n+1' , 'N', 'CA','C' (non consecutive id for ) **C_n** having patter for consecutive **name, id** *C', 'N', 'CA', 'C' , 'N', 'CA','C'* create a dictionary dC13, dC14, d15 ... where d_n is the name for each "C_n".

Comment: It isn't clear to me how you are splitting up your dictionaries.

Comment: by creating a tuple from col (name, id) as a tuple the key and [vect1, vect2, vect3] as the value ... I create the tuple for dict as: df['new_col'] = list(zip(df.name, df.id))

Comment: Ok... why is `(C, 14)` separated from `[(N, 14), (CA, 14)]`?

Comment: just for visualization for me ... clearing the space between now

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still very confused.  Usually I can overcome any misuse of terms by looking at the expected output.  However, what you've output isn't actually in any data structure.  It isn't a list, dataframe, dictionary, set, ... It looks like you printed out each row as a dictionary with some blank lines in between.  Are you suggesting you want to be able to print each row as a dictionary where the vector columns are the value and the name, id column as a tuple are the key?  I'd urge you to spell out what you want as clearly as possible.

Comment: ok, so key is the combination from name and id column, values is the vect1, vect2, vect3. What I try to do is the output to be only as a consecutive id from having exactly forming this "patern": 'C', 'N', 'CA'. Example does show sample of how will look, so in this case n=13, n+1=14 , n+2 = 15 etc.

Comment: You keep responding to me via the comments.  You need to edit your question *---> [**EDIT**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44034790/edit)<---* and use more words and a much better example.  Your attempt to explain in the comments is not working for me.

Comment: replaced the dataset, old one was confuse and simply looked like 'pd.DataFrame.to_dict' but looking for kind of algorithm implementation rather converting to a dict ... Please let me know if is clear now, did my best

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df.set_index(['name', 'id'], inplace=True, drop=True)
result = [{k: v.tolist()} for k, v in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using `pandas` and this may not be the best answer but it's still a hack that can group your data like the example you gave in your question:

```
sales = [('name', ['C', 'N', 'CA', 'C', 'N', 'CA', 'C', 'N', 'CA', 'C']),
 ('id', [13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16]),
 ('vect1', [200, 210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 200, 210, 90, 45]),
 ('vect2', [140, 215, 95, 340, 215, 95, 240, 215, 95, 65]),
 ('vect3', [240, 115, 35, 340, 115, 35, 140, 115, 35, 35])]

final = []
for m in range(len(sales[0][1])):
    name, id, *vect = [j for *_, k in sales for j, *_ in zip(k[m:m+1])]
    final.append({(name, id): vect})

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[{('C', 13): [200, 140, 240]},
 {('N', 14): [210, 215, 115]},
 {('CA', 14): [90, 95, 35]},
 {('C', 14): [200, 340, 340]},
 {('N', 15): [210, 215, 115]},
 {('CA', 15): [90, 95, 35]},
 {('C', 15): [200, 240, 140]},
 {('N', 16): [210, 215, 115]},
 {('CA', 16): [90, 95, 35]},
 {('C', 16): [45, 65, 35]}]
```